# SQL MERGE CASE UPDATE multiple columns

Tags: sql, merge, case, multiple-columns

I would appreciate any help on the following issue. I am trying this on SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to use a MERGE statement to update a column which has had a change rather than perform an update on the whole row.

When the update is performed on the column I would want the a date modified column to be updated as well.

> MERGE INTO 
>       dbo.TableA AS target
>
> > USING
> >     (
> >         SELECT *
> >         FROM dbo.dbo.TableB
> >     ) AS source
> >
> > ON 
> >     (
> >     target.ID = source.ID   AND
> >     target.NAME = source.NAME
> >     )
> >
> > WHEN MATCHED THEN
> >
> > UPDATE SET
> >
> > target.AGE =
> >
> > > > CASE WHEN target.AGE!= source.AGE
> > > >
> > > > THEN source.AGE ELSE target.AGE
> > > >
> > > > END
> > >
> > > -- I want to UPDATE the 'Date_Modified' Column if the CASE statement has made a modification to the AGE column 
> > >       ,
> >
> > target.ADDRESS =
> >
> > > > CASE WHEN target.ADDRESS != source.ADDRESS
> > > >
> > > > THEN source.ADDRESS ELSE target.ADDRESS
> > > >
> > > > END
> > >
> > > -- I want to UPDATE the 'Date_Modified' Column if the CASE statement has made a modification to the ADDRESS column
> > >       ;

Is there a way I can update the 'Date_Modified' field from within the CASE statement?

Thank you,

Comment: This has been solved:

Comment: MERGE  
 dbo.dbo.TableA AS target 
USING  
(
 SELECT *
   FROM dbo.TableB
) AS source

ON 
(
target.ID = source.ID AND
target.Name = source.name
)   
WHEN MATCHED AND 
 (

        target.AGE <> source.AGE 
 
     OR target.ADDRESS <> source.ADDRESS 
 

   
 )

THEN
 UPDATE  
 SET 
  target.End_Date = GETDATE()
 ;